# Intersection of standard line and plane

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

To find the intersection for
$$L:\frac{x-2}3=\frac{y-1}4=\frac{z+1}1$$
and a plane
$$3x-y+z=0$$
So actually what are the step by step instructions to solve their intersection?

Comment: Try calling the common value in your first two equations $t$, so $x = 3t + 2, y = 4t + 1, z = t - 1$. Now solve your third equation with respect to $t$, and substitute back into $x, y, z$ to find the coordinates of a point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equate coordinate functions of the line to a parameter $t$:
$$\frac{x-2}3=\frac{y-1}4=\frac{z+1}1=t$$
Then $x=3t+2,y=4t+1,z=t-1$. Substitute these into the plane equation:
$$3(3t+2)-(4t+1)+(t-1)=0$$
$$6t+4=0\qquad t=-\frac23$$
Then the intersection coordinates fall easily: $x=0,y=-\frac53,z=-\frac53$.

Answer (score 1):

with $$x=3t+2,y=4t+1,z=t-1$$ we get$$3(3t+2)-4t-1+t-1=0$$ solve this for $t$

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t feel like solving any equations, you can compute this intersection directly by using the Plücker matrix of the line.

By inspection, we know that the point $(2,1,-1)$ lies on the line and that the line is parallel to the vector $(3,4,1)$. Expressed in homogeneous coordinates, the line is thus the join of $\mathbf p=[2:1:-1:1]$ and $\mathbf q=[3:4:1:0]$, which can be represented by the Plücker matrix $L=\mathbf p\mathbf q^T-\mathbf q\mathbf p^T$. The plane is represented in homogeneous coordinates by $\mathbf\pi=[3:-1:1:0]$ and so the intersection of the plane and line is $$L\mathbf\pi=\mathbf p\mathbf q^T\mathbf\pi-\mathbf q\mathbf p^T\mathbf\pi = 6\mathbf p-4\mathbf q=[0:-10:-10:6],$$ which in (inhomogeneous) Cartesian coordinates is the point $\left(0,-\frac53,-\frac53\right)$.